# Avoid redeploying in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jboss, liferay, icefaces, redeploy

I have recently started using Netbeans with following stack Liferay, icefaces with jBoss. Is is necessary to clean-rebuild and redploy the app everytime the code is changed in a java file or jsp file. Is there a way to do this auto like in eclipse. Just save the file build and deploy happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not closely familiar with JBoss, but in Tomcat with certain settings you can edit JSP directly in Tomcat and see the change after page reload.

There is also a commercial tool called JRebel that allows you to make changes without redeploying. This works for JSPs, Java files and supported frameworks (e.g. for Spring it allows reload of configuration files).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but looking for jBoss and Netbeans settings.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. For NB there aren't any other posibilities. And JRebel is the only solution for reloading java classes available.